# Remove self-references from a circular list

Tags: common-lisp, circular-reference, circular-list

I have a complex circular data structure in Common Lisp:

```
(defvar xs '#1=(1 #2=(#1# 2 #3=(#2# 3 #4=(#3# 4 #1#)))))
```

How do I convert it into a non-circular list, so that every occurrence of a self-reference is replaced with a `nil`? So that instead of `(1 (#0 2 (#1 3 (#2 4 #0))))` I have `(1 (nil 2 (nil 3 (nil 4 nil))))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to know all `cons` you have encountered by using a hash table. This version works even when the loop happens in the `cdr`:

```lisp
(defun remove-ref (list &optional (value nil))
  (let ((h (make-hash-table :test #'eq)))
    (labels ((rraux (list)
               (cond ((gethash list h) value)
                     ((not (consp list)) list)
                     (t (setf (gethash list h) t)
                        (cons (rraux (car list)) 
                              (rraux (cdr list)))))))
      (rraux list))))


(remove-ref '#1=(1 2 #2=(3 4 5 . #1#) 6 7 . #1#) 'test) 
; ==> (1 2 (3 4 5 . test) 6 7 . test)
(remove-ref '#1=(1 2 #2=(3 4 5 . #1#) 6 7 . #1#)) 
; ==> (1 2 (3 4 5) 6 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just recursively iterate over the list and its sublists, remembering which ones you have encountered before:

```
(defun remove-circles (list)
  (let ((seen (make-hash-table :test 'eq)))
    (labels ((rec (datum)
               (cond ((not (listp datum))
                      datum)
                     ((gethash datum seen)
                      nil)
                     (t
                      (setf (gethash datum seen) t)
                      (mapcar #'rec datum)))))
      (rec list))))

* (defvar xs '#1=(1 #2=(#1# 2 #3=(#2# 3 #4=(#3# 4 #1#)))))
XS
* xs
#1=(1 #2=(#1# 2 #3=(#2# 3 (#3# 4 #1#))))
* (remove-circles xs)
(1 (NIL 2 (NIL 3 (NIL 4 NIL))))
```

This creates a fresh list - the original structure is not modified.